# ShortGuid with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, guid

I installed ShortGuid from NuGet and would like to use it as the key for my table. I would like to store the 22-char string in the database rather than the Guid, so it's easier to find records when debugging. How do I get Entity Framework to create this column?

I tried adding:

```
public ShortGuid NewCol { get; set; }
```

But no column was added. I tried:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
[MaxLength(22), MinLength(22), StringLength(22)]
public ShortGuid NewCol { get; set; }
```

But still no column. Presumably EF doesn't understand what I'm trying to do so it just ignores the column? It works fine if I just use Guid:

```
public Guid NewCol { get; set; }
```

I suppose I could just use a 22-char string column, but ideally I'd like to use the ShortGuid type. Is that possible?

Comment: This seems rather out of the way/"hacky" just so you can experience a better debug experience. It sounds to me like you need to refine your debugging process/tools.

Comment: Why don't you just use GUIDs in EF and just convert them to NewGuid's when you retrieve them?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan you've never found it painful to use a Guid when digging into the database when there's an error? Not sure how you're suggesting to refine the debugging methods... But it also makes for shorter & 'prettier' urls.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I thought of that and it's an option. But I'm going to be using them quite extensively and didn't want to have to have the conversions littered all over my code. Plus if I'm debugging something, then for each relationship/entity, I need to run the key through a conversion before I can search for the data in the database, and then it gets hard when looking at lots of data, remembering which Guid value I was working with.

Comment: @Sean I speculated that it would be more difficult before I used guids as pks and it honestly hasn't been a big deal. Anytime I'm working with a guid it's in a querystring and I just copy/paste into SSMS or I look up a record by another field. I guess it depends on your use case.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I'll reconsider Guids, thanks. My frustration with them is they're hard to remember, if only for a minute or two - whereas it's easy to remember ID 762 and then quickly write SQL for that (granted you can copy/paste, but if you're dealing with multiple keys in multiple tables and you're switching between them, you have to keep going: move mouse, select, copy, move mouse, paste - for each different key). Also you can't sort by the Guid so it's hard to quickly scan a table or result set for the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced something similar with Entity Framework in the past. As far as I understand, the type of a column cannot be a complex type. This is a limitation of the Entity Framework (but I am not 100% sure about this).

I will share what I usually do in these sort of situations, even though I am aware that my answer is more of a workaround than a proper answer for your question.

I create 2 properties in my class: 1) the property that will be acting as the column in the database and 2) the property I originally intended to keep in my class. The following code snippet will explain what I am trying to do.

Event.cs:

```
namespace MyContext.Model 
{
    public partial class Event 
    {
        [Key]
        public int EventId { get; set; }

        public string AccessTokenStr { get; set; }

        // [NotMapped] tells Entity Framework to not make a column for the following property
        [NotMapped]
        public ShortGuid AccessToken 
        {
            get
            {
                return new ShortGuid(AccessTokenStr);
            }

            set
            {
                AccessTokenStr = value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is probably as good a solution as there's likely to be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Map it as a complex type, but you can't use it as the primary key

Comment: I'll look into complex types, but if I can't use it as the primary key it defeats the purpose.